# target elements of json stringify to 'flash' on change

Tags: javascript

An example of what I'm trying to achieve: http://paldepind.github.io/flyd/examples/sum/

note of the flashing elements.

I have an object with a state and elements for (small) example :

```
var character = {
    initialState: function(name) {
        return {
            name,
            race: "Orc",
            age: 10,
        }
    }
}
```

This object has much more elements and methods, but that's besides that. 
One of my methods is to increment the age.

I have another code block that display's the contents of the object as a JSON structure by delivering it like so

```
<pre>{JSON.stringify(state, null, 4)}</pre>
```

In doing this I can see the contents of the object while buttons to change it. But I was hoping that on changing the state of the object, the json element that changes would 'flash' to give a more pleasing look, except I have no idea how to go about targeting it.

I know I could *not* convert it to a `JSON.stringify` and just display it as a component and have affects targeting it's state, but I was curious if doing it this route is possible.

More detail:

Before age increment

```
"Borg": {
        "name": "Borg",
        "race": "Orc",
        "class": "Barbarian",
        "age": 13,
        "weight": 260,
}
```

After age increment

```
"Borg": {
        "name": "Borg",
        "race": "Orc",
        "class": "Barbarian",
        "age": 14,  // on this change, it would flash
        "weight": 260,
}
```

I can provide more details if needed.

Comment: So you want the text inside the `<pre>` tags to be styled? If so, you should read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily want the whole content of pre change, just the element that changes from the previous. I've added more detail.

Comment: Are you using some kind of framework? Or is this vanilla js?

Comment: My point is, you cannot style content within `<pre>` tags. Did you review the link I provided? The content must be within some OTHER HTML tag to be styled. Please consider that first.

Comment: I think you’ll need to split up the <pre> tag content into child elements. In the URL you shared the section that lights up is likely separated into its own element to ensure targeting and updating that one specifically without updating anything else

Comment: as I feared, I was curious if that was a super high tech secret trick I wasn't aware of but alas my assumptions were as I assumed. Time to break it all apart.